# Is it impossible to embed Java3D in a way that I don't need to install it?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, 3d, java-3d

I'm running a big application and a small part of it includes Java 3D, the problem is many users need to use the code, but it isn't practical for everyone to install Java 3D just to run the application if they aren't even going to use that section of the application.

Is it possible through compiling an extra jar, or changing some paths, to include Java 3D in a project without installing it on a system? Or perhaps to manually include any dlls?

Comment: I believe as long as the Java3D jar is in your `CLASSPATH` (can be specified in the `manifest.mf` of your application with a relative path) and ddls are are in your `PATH` (same directory as the app jar should work automatically), everything should be fine. You could even inject Java3D classes into your application jar.

Comment: It's possible to use Java3D as any third party library without explicitly manipulating any native library since its version 1.6.0. As it relies exclusively on JOGL, you just need to provide the same JARs than the ones you use to install it on your development machine: jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demos at [java3d](https://java3d.dev.java.net/) prove that it is possible. 
You only need to include the required jar files to your projects distribution.

Comment: But don't forget about the dlls on Windows, without those it'll blow up.

Comment: @Perce This is no longer true with Java3D 1.6.0. You just need Java3D and JOGL JARs to make it work: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D JOGL 2 native libraries are available separately and in several JARs. By default, JOGL is able to detect the architecture, pick the right JARs and extract the appropriate native libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  You will need to pull the required jars and native libraries from the java3d site.  I pulled them from the java3d demos, but that requires digging through the xml launch descriptor files.

The place you'll run into the most trouble is when linking to the .so / .dll files.  This is typically specified on the classpath before your app starts, but since you don't know what platform you're using until your app starts, it's a catch22.

There are two possible solutions:
1.  Bootstrap your program with a simple class that detects the platform and sets up a new jvm (with the proper libraries specified) for the real application.
2.  Dynamically load the libraries (I've never actually used this method for native implementations, but I see no reason why it wouldn't be possible).

Unfortunately, neither method is terribly straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm going to see what I can do with the Jars and  Dlls... Right now I can build and run the application from a binary without crashing or getting a compiler error if the system doesn't have J3D, but once they try and access the J3D section it'll throw exceptions.

Comment: Hey Kyle,

That's because you have linked the java wrapper, but haven't linked the native code.  Thus, the JVM doesn't blow up until it tries to load the native code (upon first use).

Comment: This complicated method is no longer necessary since Java3D 1.6.0 as it relies exclusively on JOGL which is able to extract the appropriate native libraries from the JARs and load them.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this with no problems (and many users tested that it works, Windows OS) by simply adding the jars to the classpath and dropping the appropriate dlls into the "working" directory where the .bat file running Java started.  One catch is I had to have two bat files - one 32 bit and one 64 bit.  Each bat file copy/renames the appropriate dll to j3dcore-ogl.dll, since depending on which version of Java (32/64 bit) you're running, a different jar is needed.

Example .bat file:

del j3dcore-ogl.dll
copy j3dcore-ogl-64.dll j3dcore-ogl.dll
java -Xmx2048m -classpath ./YourJar.jar;./lib/tinylaf.jar;./lib/j3dcore.jar;./lib/j3dutils.jar;./lib/vecmath.jar your.package.MainClass
@pause

Comment: j3dcore-ogl DLL is no longer available in Java3D 1.6.0. Please edit your answer, mention that it only works with Java3D <= 1.5.2.